Is it consistent to say the Father speaks in Jesus's name, given their unity in divine work?
Jn. 14:10 ASV

Believest thou not that I am in the Father, and the Father in me? the words that I say unto you I speak not from myself: but the Father abiding in me doeth his works.

If Jesus states that the words He speaks are not His own but those of the Father dwelling in Him, is it theologically consistent to consider that the Father, in speaking through Jesus, is also speaking in Jesus's name, given their unity in divine work and mission?

There is no Bible text anywhere that says, "The Father speaks in Jesus' name" (or, words to that effect). The only place in the Bible to look for any information about this would be in the Christian Greek scriptures. The Hebrew scriptures concluded 400 years before Jesus came into the world, so there's no use looking there.
The text in question is interesting, as it does not say the Father speaks in Jesus' name. It says Jesus speaks the words of the Father, yet then says the Father does "his works" - not "his words" - through Jesus.
Further, the Apostle John, in the prologue of his gospel account, says that the Word of God became flesh, and came to declare the Father to us (John 1:18). Jesus used words to declare the truth about the Father. Jesus also said that his ministry on Earth had the witness (authority) of the Father, in whose name he came (John 8:16-18 & 28-29). But nowhere does it say that God spoke in Jesus' name.
On the contrary, the few occasions where the Father spoke from heaven while Jesus was on Earth, it is clear that Jesus was not speaking, but his Father was speaking about Jesus as being his Son, and that people were to listen to Jesus. See 2 Peter 1:16-18. The voice of the Father was never heard to say, "I speak in the authority of, and in the name of, Jesus Christ." It was always the other way around. Jesus spoke in the authority of, and in the name of God the Father. That was because the Word of God had lowered himself to be a servant on Earth. He had abased himself. He came to open up the way to the Father.
But the Father and the Son are as one, as Jesus said in the text in question. Jesus' spoken words glorify the Father, and the Father's spoken words glorify the Son.

In my understanding, your text contradicts Hebrews 1:1-2 and Luke 9:35

@Betho's  I gave 4 texts, not 1. I then read your answer, and would only add that we are agreed that there is "inseparable unity in divine action" and about "the Trinitarian understanding that while the Father and Son are distinct persons, their work and voice are unified." As you said in your last para. There is no contradiction in my answer re. Heb. 1:1-2 & Lk 9:35. I'm simply focused on the fact that while scripture says Jesus speaks the Father's words, and the Father tells us to listen to what Jesus says, it never actually says the Father speaks in Jesus' name.

Theologically, it is consistent to say that the Father speaks in Jesus's name, given their unity in divine work and mission. This unity is illuminated by several key biblical passages:

Hebrews 1:1-2:
"God, having of old time spoken unto the fathers in the prophets by divers portions and in divers manners, hath at the end of these days spoken unto us in his Son, whom he appointed heir of all things, through whom also he made the worlds" (ASV).
Here, God’s ultimate revelation comes through Jesus. By speaking in and through the Son, the Father’s voice is essentially communicated in the name and person of Jesus.

Luke 9:35:
"And a voice came out of the cloud, saying, This is my Son, my chosen: hear ye him" (ASV).
The Father explicitly commands that Jesus be heard, which aligns with the idea that Jesus serves as the full manifestation of the Father’s will and voice. In this sense, the Father’s words are inseparable from Jesus’s mission and identity.

John 14:10:
Jesus underscores His unity with the Father, stating, "the words that I say unto you I speak not from myself: but the Father abiding in me doeth his works" (ASV).
This indicates that Jesus speaks with the authority and words of the Father, reflecting their perfect unity in mission and purpose. Since Jesus "abides in the Father" and the Father speaks through Him, it can be understood that the Father’s speech is intrinsically linked to the identity and mission of Jesus.

Unity in Name and Action:
Because Jesus is the Word (Logos) through whom the Father has chosen to reveal Himself, everything the Father speaks or does is mediated by and through Jesus (John 1:1-3). The name of Jesus becomes the vessel of divine revelation and authority, as shown in Philippians 2:9-11, where Jesus is exalted above all names.


Thus, theologically, the Father speaking through Jesus is not only consistent with speaking in Jesus’s name but necessary, given their inseparable unity in divine action. This concept reinforces the Trinitarian understanding that while the Father and Son are distinct persons, their work and voice are unified.
